# Special characters (French characters) are not allowed in mailto in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, email

I am developing a project in French language. I have an issue on the project in **mailto**. I have used the below code. After clicking on the below link, the mailbox opens with the content but the mailbox does not support the French characters.
This issue happens on **outlook** and **windows mail**.

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=Mon projet&body=Bonjour, %0AJ’ai pensé que cette propriété pourrait vous intéresser: www.myproject.com/propriété">Mail</a>
```

The content shown in the mailbox.

```
Bonjour, 
Jâ€™ai pensÃ© que cette propriÃ©tÃ© pourrait vous intÃ©resser: www.myproject.com/propriÃ©tÃ©10:44
```

I want the below content in the mailbox.

```
Bonjour, 
J’ai pensé que cette propriété pourrait vous intéresser: www.myproject.com/propriété
```

Please provide a solution for the above issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have applied all solution but no one answered working for windows live mail.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use encodeURI first:

```js
var url = "mailto:?subject=Mon projet&body=Bonjour, %0AJ’ai pensé que cette propriété pourrait vous intéresser: www.myproject.com/propriété";
url = encodeURI(url);
alert(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var url = "mailto:?subject=Mon projet&body=Bonjour, %0AJ’ai pensé que cette propriété pourrait vous intéresser: www.myproject.com/propriété";
url = encodeURI(url);
alert(url);
document.write("<a href='"+url+"'>Mail</a>");
```